# In Django, can you filter a queryset by a parent (uses ForeignKey field) model's field value?

Tags: python, django

Let's say you have models defined for Transaction, Category, and TransactionDetail, like so:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
   details = models.ForeignKey(TransactionDetails, verbose_name="Transaction Details", on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='',null=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Transaction Category", on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='')

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Category Name", default="")
   
class TransactionDetails(models.Model):
   value = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Transaction Detail", default="")
```

In views.py I am trying to figure out how to filter TransactionDetails objects that are attached to a Transaction.details field AND have a specific Transaction.Category.name.
In other words, I'd like to return a queryset of TransactionDetails that are related to Transaction objects with a category.name of "uncategorized".

I understand how to use the objects manager filter for the other way around:

```
uncatTransactions = Transaction.objects.filter(category__name="Uncategorized")
```

But am unsure how this would be done for TransactionDetails:

```
uncategorizedTrxDetails = TransactionDetails.objects.filter(referenceToParentUsingForeignKey__category__name="Uncategorized")
```

Comment: Simply `uncatTransactions.details.filter(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter with:

```
TransactionDetails.objects.filter(transaction__category__name='Uncategorized')
```